# Streets of Mauritius

Tags: data-request, openstreetmap

I am looking for an index of all streets in Mauritius.

Google Maps and OpenStreetMap are not detailed enough, for instance they do not contain "Rue des Tourterelles" in the "Baie du tombeau" area, which [exists](http://wap.companiesinmauritius.com/de/chin-hao-shipping-supplies-cc-ltd.Xb.mauritius-company-profile.html).

I could not find anything on the [government's website](https://www.gov.mu).

Comment: I'm afraid if it's not in Google Maps, you're not going to find open data for it. They'd have found it by now, no? Are you just looking for a list of names? Or for GIS data? OpenStreetMap sometimes convenes groups to go out and gather map data. Maybe you can motivate some Mauritians to have a "mappy hour"?

Answer (score 1):

They have a map (Google tiles) with waypoints but no additional road data: [gov.mu/English/Map/Pages/default.aspx](http://gov.mu/English/Map/Pages/default.aspx) I didn't see a data download link on the page, but I'll keep digging.

I did find that their police utilize services from SuperMap (which is not open source/data): http://www.supermap.com/en/html/solutions722161.html

And for the sake of context, here is a paper discussing the need for more GIS in Mauritius not too long ago: http://www.ncgia.ucsb.edu/conf/gishe97/program_files/papers/beedasy.html